How to create an excel formula using LET and other dynamic array functions which gives an calculated output of each column?
I have a table like this which stores marks of students in different subjects




Name
Class
ID
Math
English
Hindi




Tony
5
1
39
30
30


Andrew
5
2
40
20
20


Mark
5
3
40
10
30



and a tabel like this which sets the maximum marks of the subject




Subject
Max Marks




Math
40


English
30


Hindi
30



I want to create a excel formula that will return this by calculating the percentage of marks obtained in each subject and grade it accordingly and arranges the data to this

and could generate a excel function using AI which is =LET( Data, Table1, Headers, {"Name","Class","ID","Math","Math Grade","English","English Grade","Hindi","Hindi Grade"}, GradeThresholds, Table2, GetMaxMarks, LAMBDA(Subject, IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Max Marks], MATCH(Subject, Table2[Subject], 0)), "Subject Not Found") ), Grades, LAMBDA(Score,MaxMarks, IFS( Score / MaxMarks >= 0.9, "A", Score / MaxMarks >= 0.75, "B", Score / MaxMarks >= 0.6, "C", Score / MaxMarks >= 0.5, "D", TRUE, "F" ) ), MathMaxMarks, GetMaxMarks("Math"), EnglishMaxMarks, GetMaxMarks("English"), HindiMaxMarks, GetMaxMarks("Hindi"), MathGrades, Grades(INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Math",Table1[#Headers],0)), MathMaxMarks), EnglishGrades, Grades(INDEX(Data,,MATCH("English",Table1[#Headers],0)), EnglishMaxMarks), HindiGrades, Grades(INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Hindi",Table1[#Headers],0)), HindiMaxMarks), ExpandedTable, HSTACK( INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Name",Table1[#Headers],0)), INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Class",Table1[#Headers],0)), INDEX(Data,,MATCH("ID",Table1[#Headers],0)), INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Math",Table1[#Headers],0)), MathGrades, INDEX(Data,,MATCH("English",Table1[#Headers],0)), EnglishGrades, INDEX(Data,,MATCH("Hindi",Table1[#Headers],0)), HindiGrades ), VSTACK(Headers, ExpandedTable) )
which works perfectly, but i want the formula to be dynamic and adjust itself as to i will be adding new subjects to the tables and don't want to hardcode the subject names into the formula each time I add a new subject.

Without taking this apart, I suggest you make another table that contains the dynamic formulas for grade cut-off scores by subject, then the students' grades are a simple lookup by subject and range VLookup by score.

Not a bad question.

I don't know who all downvoted the question, but I found it a nice challenge and it is well asked.

I created this solution for you:

[A14]=LET(
  marks,LAMBDA(sc,subj,
    LET(r,sc/XLOOKUP(subj,Table2[Subject],Table2[Max Marks]),
      IF(r<0.5,"F",CHAR(71-INT(20*r/3)))
    )
  ),
  REDUCE(
    Table1[[#All],[Name]:[ID]],
    SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(Table1)-3,4),
    LAMBDA(a,v,
      HSTACK(a,
        CHOOSECOLS(Table1[#All],v),
        VSTACK(INDEX(Table1[#All],1,v)&" Grade",
          marks(CHOOSECOLS(Table1,v),INDEX(Table1[#All],1,v))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

Where Table1 is the first table, Table2 is the second table. You can easily add new rows and columns in Table1 and new rows in Table2 without formula modification.

what a blessing! thanks for the solution it works perfectly you saved the day. I am so so thankful...

Another option skipping the max score table:
=REDUCE(A1:C4,{1,2,3},
 LAMBDA(x,y,
        LET(i,CHOOSECOLS(D1:F4,y),
            n,DROP(i,1),
HSTACK(x,
       i,
       VSTACK(TAKE(i,1)&" Grade",
              XLOOKUP(n/MAX(n),{0.9,0.75,0.6,0.5},{"A","B","C","D"},"F",-1))))))

Table references:
=REDUCE(Table1[[#All],[Name]:[ID]],{1,2,3},
 LAMBDA(x,y,
        LET(i,CHOOSECOLS(Table1[[#All],[Math]:[Hindi]],y),
        n,DROP(i,1),
HSTACK(x,
       i,
       VSTACK(TAKE(i,1)&" Grade",
              XLOOKUP(n/MAX(n),{0.9,0.75,0.6,0.5},{"A","B","C","D"},"F",-1))))))

Fully dynamic:
=LET(table,Table1[#All],
     subjects,DROP(table,,3),
REDUCE(TAKE(table,,3),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(subjects)),
LAMBDA(x,y,
   LET(i,CHOOSECOLS(subjects,y),
       n,DROP(i,1),
HSTACK(x,
       i,
       VSTACK(TAKE(i,1)&" Grade",
              XLOOKUP(n/MAX(n),{0.9,0.75,0.6,0.5},{"A","B","C","D"},"F",-1)))))))


Well refactored, but it can be a case when nobody has got the max score.

@rotabor I understood the question as having a max mark for each subject and if a subject is added, also the max for that gets added (or gets calculated without adding in this case).

@P.b thanks a lot for your answer it's very interesting how the function uses the max mark scored by a  student to calculate and assign the grades respectively, I will definitely use this in other projects, but for this question I have to set a standard max mark in another table, since sometimes not even 1 student might score a max mark.

You should be able to use the same concept without REDUCE if you replace MAX with XLOOKUP (or even TOROW(Table2[Max Marks]) if the subjects are always in the same order in both tables). For example: =LET(n,3,subj,DROP(Table1[#Headers],,n),vals,XLOOKUP(DROP(Table1,,n)/XLOOKUP(subj,Table2[Subject],Table2[Max Marks]),{0.9,0.75,0.6,0.5},{"A","B","C","D"},"F",-1,-2),cols,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table1)),SORTBY(HSTACK(Table1[#All],VSTACK(subj&" Grade",vals)),HSTACK(cols,DROP(cols,,n)))) Cheers! ;)

Nice one @DjC, however I think this was directed to Rotabor's answers, since it uses his logic, not mine. Mine skips the presence of table 2 entirely. (You could store that as =GROUPBY(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(DROP(Table1,,3)),DROP(Table1[#Headers],,3)),2),TOCOL(DROP(Table1,,3),1),MAX,,0) )

Since it's about Table2 again, it contains predefined maximum marks for each subject to get the absolute score not relative as you guess. I never met such relative scoring system.

@DjC It's a nice finding to replace reduce's hstacking by appropriate sorting.

@rotabor =LET(table,Table1[#All],subjects,DROP(table,,3),REDUCE(TAKE(table,,3),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(subjects)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(i,CHOOSECOLS(subjects,y),n,DROP(i,1),HSTACK(x,i,VSTACK(@i&" Grade",XLOOKUP(n/VLOOKUP(@i,Table2,2,),{0.9,0.75,0.6,0.5},{"A","B","C","D"},"F",-1))))))) including table2

No worries. It shared some commonalities with both of your answers, which is why I didn't post it as another answer. In any case, what the heck are we all doing here on this day of the year, lol. xD

@DjC Merry XMATCH
